# VSTS changed to DevOps, now our Nuget Packages are not authenticating. What do we do?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, devops

We are now getting:

> Failed to retrieve metadata from source and Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)

errors when reading packages that have always worked in the past.

We noticed that Microsoft changed to `DevOps` without sending us a warning so we could prepare our team for an outage of services. This is unfortunate, but any workaround would be greatly appreciated!

Things we have checked already: the URL for the packages, as shown in `Connect to feed` is the same in `DevOps` as it was in `VSTS`. Reloading visual studio, did nothing, and also reconnecting team services from visual studio did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have just waited, we can all (all people on the team) access what we need now. It must have been a temporary glitch as they proceeded with their migration to devops.

Comment: You could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.